# Can't setup TwistPHP. File not found but it's right there

Tags: php

I am trying to setup the [TwistPHP](https://twistphp.com/installation) framework for my new website, and I've run into a problem.

On their Getting Started page, you're told to paste the `twist` folder into root dir, then include the framework file in your index page. And to then run your site and follow the GUI wizard to set things up.

However, following the steps, all I get is a 404 Not Found error. I then decided to directly run the framework.php page and still, I got a 404.

My code is:

index.php:

```
<?php require_once 'twist/framework.php';
```

Why am I getting a 404 on a page that *does* exist, and how can I fix it?

[image: Showing folder and file structure to show that all files there there and in the right place.]

Upon discovering the log file (it was a hidden file), I see that it logs two exceptions where it cannot find certain files. But this is how the framework was setup, so how am I supposed to fix it? This is a fresh untouched download. Nothing has been changed.

```
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2]
include_once(C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Royal Plaza\Royal Plaza\twist/modules//.gitignore/register.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2]
include_once(): Failed opening 'C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Royal Plaza\Royal Plaza\twist/modules//.gitignore/register.php' for inclusion
(include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Notice: [8] Undefined index: title
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Notice: [8] Undefined index: title
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2] mkdir(): Invalid argument
[2015-06-11 08:04:46] Warning: [2]
file_put_contents(C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Royal Plaza\Royal Plaza/cache/pkgTemplate/\twist-core/templates//system/error-page.tpl.twi):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 404 has nothing to do with `include`/`require` - your web server can't find index.php (or whatever other file you're trying to access). On what URL does the 404 occur?

Comment: index.php is there in the root dir. The 404 occurs when I go to framework.php and index.php. Either one produces the same result; a 404. I've looked into log file (which I didn't realise existed til now) and am updating my question with more details.

Comment: I lost it at `.gitignore`. There isn't an actual *folder* named like that in twist/modules, is there? Also, what is the full path to `index.php` on the file system? And what web server are you using?

Comment: @Siguza That's where I got lost, too. No, there is no gitignore folder. The path to index.php is: C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Royal Plaza\Royal Plaza\index.php - I'm using WAMPSERVER and PHP Tools for Visual Studio. Both run great with other frameworks and I've been using them for months. So not sure which one is causing the issue.

Comment: My guess is that a setting is messed up somewhere, namely containing a `/.gitignore`. Because I doubt a serious framework would use that as a folder name. Are you using `open_basedir` (in php.ini)? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: @Siguza I just checked; open_basedir is commented-out: `;open_basedir =`

Comment: @Siguza You might be interested, but I am posting an answer. I have managed to get the setup page to display in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the creators of Twist. I'm sorry you are having problems setting up the framework. It sounds like a server configuration issue, but you also have a very old copy of the framework.

Check out the latest verion of TwistPHP (https://twistphp.com)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can't wait to see what happens. I'm still looking forward to using Twist.

Answer (score 1):

**TwistPHP 3** has now been released (https://twistphp.com) you should really consider using the new MVC version. It is faster, more reliable and has many new features over its predecessors.

**However in answer to the question:**

The register.php file warnings should not be causing any problems with the output of the setup wizard, the reason that the errors are present is that the framework thinks the .gitignore files are modules and is trying to include them.

.gitignore files are used to ensure that folders remain in a github repository even though they are empty. These files can be removed from live projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works.

---

Running `index.php` or `framework.php` in the browser results in a 404 Not Found error.

But, if you close all files in Visual Studio, and ensure that only your Project Name is selected in Solution Explorer, then hit F5 (Debug), the Wizard will appear in the browser.